# C# Read Block Implementation

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader

I am writing a program which is parsing large, non-predictable files. No problem with this part. I have been using the code below, looping through ReadLine until the end of the document to keep the memory footprint low. My problem being is an `OutOfMemoryException` when a line is simply too long.

```
System.IO.StreamReader casereader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dumplocation);
string line;
while ((line = casereader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    foreach (Match m in linkParser.Matches(line))
    {
        Console.Write(displaytext);
        Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
        XMLWrite.Start(m.Value, displaytext, dumplocation, line);
    }
}
```

XMLWrite is just writing any strings that match my Regex Function to an XML Document. The Regex function is a simple email search. The issue occurs when ReadLine is called and the application finds an extremely long line in the file I am reading(I can see this as the memory usage in task manger climbs and climbs as it populates the string 'line'). Eventually it runs out of memory and crashes. What I want to do is read pre defined blocks (e.g 8,000 characters) and then run these one at a time through the same process. This means that I will then always know the length of string line (8,000 chars) and should not receive and out of memory exception. Does my logic seem logic!? I am looking for the best way to implement ReadBlock as currently I am unable to get it working.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Is the problem that you're *still* getting out of memory?  If not, what is your question? You imply that the first block of code has the OOM problem and reading a predefined block fixes that.

Comment: And what's happening? Errors?

Comment: what error do you get? What is the problem that you have? I did not try your code in visual studio but the logic seems good... Is it that the compiler is complaining?

Comment: You're plan won't work because you may chop a word in half that was needed in your Regex. You're going to have to use a parser. Or change the process to 64bit.

Comment: You probably want to take a look at this post since you are trying to use readblock and expecting full lines. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/csharpgeneral/thread/642b20be-586a-41ca-9140-b541cbac2570

Comment: Hi sorry I did not make it clear enough. My block of code simply does not work. I'm not sure how to implement the ReadBlock function correctly. Brannon I had thought about this problem but it is not an issue, the document is already a muddle of characters and I am sure that because of this I am already missing out on some matches using the ReadLine method.

Comment: "Does not work" is not clear, errors, exceptions, unexpected values, etc?

Comment: If your `String` is throwing an `OutOfMemoryException` it doesn't matter how you populate the `String`, you are going to run out of memory. What is your linkParser `Regex` doing? Perhaps this can be changed so you can read partial lines.

Comment: Need to see more code. Types are important. What is `linkParser`, `buffer` and `casereader` for example. Also in second block what is `XMLWrite` about, I thought you were just trying to find alterative to first block of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code

```
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(yourPath)) 
            {
                //This is an arbitrary size for this example.
                char[] c = null;

                while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
                {
                    c = new char[5];//Read block of 5 characters
                    sr.Read(c, 0, c.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine(c); //print block
                }
            }
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824.aspx

Comment: Came across this example but have not had any luck implementing it. Thanks anyway

Comment: @BenCollins Show some effort.   Where did that simple example fail?

Answer (score 1):

**line = buffer.ToString();**
This statement should be to blame. buffer is a char array, and its ToString() methods just return System.char[].

Answer (score -1):

Use: line= new string(buffer);
Instead